# Hive port is closed

Tags: hadoop, fiware, fiware-cosmos

I want to launch Hive queries remotely.

For that, I am using the hive-jdbc library (0.14.0 version) and hadoop-core (1.2.1 version).

Some weeks ago, I launch the following code:

```
    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:hive://cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org:10000/default", "user",
            "password");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String sql = "select * from table_name";
    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (res.next()) {
        System.out.println("value: " + res.getString(1));
    }
```

and it works, but now I am getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not establish connection to cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org:10000/default: java.net.ConnectException: Conexión rehusada
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:117)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
```

I saw that now the Hive port (10000) is closed.

So, I am wondering what is the correct way to use a remote hive client to access to cosmos, or If I have to change the way to get data from cosmos.

Comment: Can you check whether the hiveserver2 is running or not.

Comment: Is not running, the version of Hive is 0.7.1, so in this version is not the hiveserver2. That is introduced in 0.11 version.

Comment: Start the hive-server. This is available in that version. hive --service hiveserver &

Comment: There was a network problem, now it is working.